# Sort list of strings with starting number in powershell

Tags: sorting, powershell, filenames

i'm new to powershell so any help is much appreciated.

I have an list of strings (filenames) and they start with a number eg. "1. first file", "2. second file" ... "21. twenty-first file".

and I want to sort it in the order of the starting number. But when I do "$List | sort {$_.Name} -Unique" it will start with "1. " and then the next item is "11." instead of "2."

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$test = @('1. First', '2. Second', '11. Eleventh')
$sort = @()
foreach($item in $test){
  $item -match '^(\d+).*'
  $temp = New-Object PSCustomObject -property @{'Number' = [int]$matches[1]}
  $sort += $temp
}
$sort | Sort-Object Number | Select-Object Data
```

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is that you missed a "}" after "[int]$matches[1]". But with that fixed it worked great! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Woops, yeah I tested it as a oneliner at the prompt and missed that when I changed it to a script.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the previous answer a little, you could do this:

```powershell
$test | Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression={[int]$_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf('.'))}; Ascending=$true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
$col = @(
'1. first file'
'2. second file'
'11. eleventh file'
'21. twenty-first file'
)

$ht = @{}
$col | foreach {$ht[$_ -replace '\D+$'] = $_}
[int[]]$ht.keys | sort | foreach {$ht["$_"] }

1. first file
2. second file
11. eleventh file
21. twenty-first file
```